Using @splinetool/react-spline on a Local Network
I'm trying to use the @splinetool/react-spline library on a local network without Internet access. Unfortunately, it seems the library relies on Internet endpoints, which has made it challenging to get it working locally despite multiple attempts.
If anyone has experience with this or can suggest a solution, I’d greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you!
